# this error is coming while serving static file in express js

Tags: node.js

Refused to load the image 'http://localhost:8000/favicon.ico' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers try to request /favicon.ico from the root folder on the server, to show an icon in the browser tab. Favicon is the icon which is displayed alongside the website name. i.e. The f logo in facebook is the favicon for it.

If you want to avoid this request error:
-Provide favicon.ico file .
-Set no content using the below

```
exp.get('/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204));
```